# Dynamically constructing URL Parameter?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am constructing a URL parameter dynamically & i am facing some problem.  I have an array which contains currently 2 object in this manner

```
NSArray *myArrays=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"123",@"456", nil];
```

but it may contain "N" number of object in future.

Right now i am manually convert it to it like this

```
id params = @{@"id": @"{\"request\":[\"123\",\" 456\"]}"};
```

But how can i create a dynamic way so that wheather it will be 2 or 200 it will give me above this manner.

Comment: Is there anything specific to AFNetworking? And what exactly are you trying to do? Putting objects in a string?

Comment: I am using AFNetworking for my network operation.

Comment: Sure, but AFNetoworking is not part of your issue here, is it?

Comment: is the array supposed to be one parameter and you want to serialize it to a url parameter?

Comment: Your code makes no sense. Could you please show what the _actual URL_ is ultimately supposed to look like?

Comment: The URL format is like this https://abc.xyz.com/status?id={"request":["123"," 456"]}

Comment: If the number of items in that array can be that many then you should consider passing that data not in the URL, but in the body of your HTTP request (so a POST instead of a GET), as the size of the URL is limited to something like 4kB.

Comment: Use `NSMutableString`. Iterate the array and build up the string.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
    NSArray *arr = @[@"one", @"two"];
    NSMutableString *params = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"{\"request\":[\""];
    [params appendString:[arr componentsJoinedByString:@"\",\" "]];
    [params appendString:@"\"]}"];
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you correctly, you want your string to look like this:

> abc.xyz.com/status?id={"request":["123"," 456"]}

So what you could do is break this up into dynamic parts and build those all together.

```
NSArray *array = @[@"123, ", @"456"]; // leave off comma for last element in array
NSString *urlPrefix = @"abc.xyz.com"; // Or I suppose you can make this dynamic
NSString *urlIntermediate = @"/status?id={";
NSMutableString *requestWithArray = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"\"request\":["];

for (NSString *s in array) {
    [requestWithArray appendString:s];
}

NSString *finalURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@]}", urlPrefix, urlIntermediate, requestWithArray];

NSLog(@"%@", finalURL);
```

Comment: Why would the array of number strings already have commas and spaces (hint - they don't)?

Comment: I did that for the sake of simplicity and, since they are strings, it certainly wouldn't be hard to append that unto all but the last. The main thing to take away was from this is the process: Get the first part, get the second part, get the third part by iterating through the array, and concatenate them.